# NOSUCHELEMENTEXCEPTION: unable to locate dropdown inside the table

Tags: selenium, select, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

The `dropdown` is inside the table.

Here is my HTML CODE:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table notification-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>PRODUCT CODE</th>
        <th>WEIGHT</th>
        <th>AVAIL</th>
        <th>LOT NUMBER</th>
        <th>STORE QTY</th>
        <th>STORAGE LOC</th>
        <th>STORAGE POINT</th>
        <th/>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Chicken</td>
        <td>AG0000</td>
        <td>2Kg</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>57</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
          <div class="styled-select slate quantity">
            <select id="stockLoc_66" class="cursor stockLocationListItem stockSelectItem selected" name="stockLoc_66">
              <option value="">Select One</option>
              <option value="Loc1">Loc1</option>
              <option value="Loc2">Loc2</option>
              <option value="Loc3">Loc3</option>
              <option value="hgfhf">hgfhf</option>
              <option value="123">123</option>
              <option value="Loc 7">Loc 7</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

My selenium code to locate and select dropdown inside the table is:

```
WebElement allocationtable = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table[@class='table notification-table']"));
List<WebElement> rows = allocationtable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for (WebElement eachrow : rows)
{
    List<WebElement> columns = eachrow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for (WebElement eachcolumn : columns)
    {
        String elementtext = "STORAGE LOC";
        String elementtext2 = "STORAGE POINT";
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='stockLoc_66']")));
        Select storagelocation = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='stockLoc_66']")));
        ...
    }
}
```

It get a `NoSuchElementException` on

```
By.xpath(".//*[@id='stockLoc_66']")
```

Comment: I didn't understand why you are using xpath when you can use By.id()  directly.

Comment: Please post a link to the page so we can see the full HTML. Something else is clearly going on here that you haven't described. Which line has the issue? You've pointed out a locator that's on multiple lines. Also post the full exception message. Have you checked for iframes, etc.?

Comment: Is there more than one element on the page with `id="stockLoc_66"`?

Comment: Only the 7th cell of each tbody row includes the select, when iterate on the first cell, it has no select inside, so report the exception.

Comment: @JeffC no there only one element on the page with id="stockLoc_66

Comment: Please answer my other questions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is only the 7th cell of each tbody row includes the select, so when the loop iterate on the first cell, there is no select inside it, so the wait report NoSuchElement exception.

Comment: The locator he is using to find the select is just an ID. It doesn't matter where it is in the HTML. His code to loop through the rows and cells doesn't alter the locator he's using so the search is not relative to where he is.

Answer (score 0):

Try with name

```
driver.findElement(By.name("stockLoc_66"));
```

or try xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@id='stockLoc_66']"));
```

Comment: same issue occurs. It doesn't find by 'name' also

Comment: try with class name also. can u share URL

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of missing information that would help narrow down an answer but for starters, you can simplify your code which might help narrow down the problem. You don't need all the looping through rows and cells to find the `SELECT`. The code below should get the element just fine.

```
Select stockLocation = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("stockLoc_66"))));
stockLocation.selectByVisibleText(...);
```

If that doesn't work. Make sure it's not in an iframe, make sure there's not more than one element with `id='stockLoc_66'`, etc.

Don't use XPath when you are locating an element using only an ID. There's no need. CSS Selectors and IDs are better supported and faster than XPath.

Answer (score 0):

The iterations through different `rows` and `columns` looks as a overhead to me. Though @JeffC 's Answer looks pretty perfect but we may require to cover some more boundary conditions.  @JeffC in his Answer have used `visibilityOfElementLocated` clause as `ExpectedConditions` which will handle the expectations while checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible.

However I will get a bit more granular and use `elementToBeSelected` clause as `ExpectedConditions` which will handle the expectations while checking if the given element is selected as follows:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(By.id("stockLoc_66")));
Select storagelocation = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("stockLoc_66")));
storagelocation.selectByValue("Loc1");
```